# Where to store config info for spring mvc 3.x

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Where is a good place to store custom config info in spring mvc 3.x and how would I access that info globally via any controller?

Is there a built in config manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume 'custom config' means a configuration file the code reads / you / your operations team can update?

One easy solution is to use spring beans xml configuration file and deploy your war in exploded fashion.

Create a configuration java class:

```
// File: MyConfig.java ------------------------------------
public class MyConfig {
  private String supportEmail;
  private String websiteName;
  // getters & setters..
}
```

Configure the class as a Spring bean and set its properties on your spring beans xml file (can also create a new file and use `<import resource="..."/>`):

```
// File: root-context.xml ----------------------------------------
<beans ...>
  ...
  <bean class="com.mycompany.MyConfig">
    <property name="supportEmail" value="support@mycompany.com"/>
    <property name="websiteName" value="Hello Site"/>
  </bean>
  ...
</beans>
```

Inject your configuration class (eg: in a controller)

```
// File: HelloController.java ------------------------------------
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {
  @Autowired MyConfig config;
  // ...
}
```

However updates to the configuration would require re-deploy / server restarts

Comment: This is awesome and exactly what I was looking for regarding custom web.config data.  Thank you!

Comment: What if I wanted to store a complete xml file as a separate config.  That is if I had something like <config><contactInfo><supportEmail/><websiteName/></contactinfo>

Comment: This method won't be suitable. Maybe take a look at JAXB, you can bind xml into java objects by using simple annotations

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `<context:property-placeholder>`.

It looks like this.

myapp.properties:

`foo=bar`

spring beans xml:

`<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myapp.properties"/>`

Or

`<context:property-placeholder location="file:///path/to/myapp.properties"/>`

Controller:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
...

@Controller
public class Controller {

  @Value("${foo}")
  private String foo;
```

If you want to get properties programmatically, you can use `Environment` with `@PropertySource`.

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:myapp.properties")
public class AppConfig {

  @Bean
  public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class Controller {

  @Value("${foo}")
  private String foo;

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @RequestMapping(value = "dosomething")
  public String doSomething() {
    env.getProperty("foo");
    ...
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just out of curiosity is Map / List injection supported?

Comment: @gerrytan: You can use `Environment` with `@PropertySource`. I have edited my answer.